# RestTemplate ClientHttpResponse.getBody() throws I/O Error

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

I'm using Spring RestTemplate to make RESTful calls. I'm also using a custom ClientHttpRequestInterceptor to log the request and response for debugging purposes.

In order to read the response multiple times (once for the logging, once for processing) I use a BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory. Here's the setup:

```
ClientHttpRequestInterceptor ri = new LoggingRequestInterceptor();
List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> ris = new ArrayList<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor>();
ris.add(ri);
restTemplate.setInterceptors(ris);
restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new InterceptingClientHttpRequestFactory(
        new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory()) , ris));
```

I'm testing this system right now against a request that returns a 422 response and am having problems. From within the intercept method of my custom ClientHttpRequestInterceptor:

```
ClientHttpResponse response = execution.execute(request, body);
if(response.getBody() != null) {
    logger.trace(IOUtils.toString(response.getBody(), "UTF-8"));
}
```

The response.getBody() throws an exception:

> org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error:
>   Server returned HTTP response code: 422 for URL:
>   https://testurl.com/admin/orders/564/fulfill.json;
>   nested exception is java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response
>   code: 422 for URL:
>   https://testurl.com/admin/orders/564/fulfill.json
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:461)
>   ~[spring-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:409)
>   ~[spring-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]

Not sure why this happens, but I turned on the debugger and I set up a watch expression for request.getBody(). The call to request.getBody() being made in that context before it gets to my actual code **fixes** the error.

Comment: where are your xml configurations for resttemplate

Comment: Same here. Another interesting behavior: calling `response.getStatusCode()` prior to `response.getBody()` also "fixes" the problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47429978/resttemplate-response-getbody-throws-exception-on-4-and-5-errors-for-put-and

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `IOException` thrown from `sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection` which `RestTemplate` uses by default. Looking the source in grepcode, `getInputStream()` throws `IOException` if the HTTP status code is 4xx  (for 404 or 410 it throws a more specific `FileNotFoundException`)

To get around this, you need to supply a different `HttpURLConnection` implementation via the `ClientHttpRequestFactory` that is used as a constructor parameter to `RestTemplate`, or injected into it with the `requestFactory` property. For example

```
 HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
 RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(factory);
```

Doing this via Spring injection is an exercise left for the reader :-)