# ClientHttpResponse.getBody() throws ResourceAccessException when response code is 401

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

I am trying to log the request-response pairs for every request. The problem is that when the response code is `401`, `ClientHttpResponse.getBody()` throws a ResourceAccessException and i cannot read the response body.

This is the RestTemplate configuration

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

// Added this requestFactory to make response object readable more than once.
ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory =
        new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory());
restTemplate.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);
restTemplate.getInterceptors().add(new RequestLoggingInterceptor(vCloudRequest.getAction(),httpHeaders));
    restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new RequestErrorHandler());

return restTemplate;
```

The last line of the interceptor below throws the following exception.

How can i resolve this problem?

> org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on
>   POST request for "https://example.com/api/sessions": Server returned
>   HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://example.com/api/sessions;
>   nested exception is java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response
>   code: 401 for URL: https://example.com.11/api/sessions

This is the related part of the interceptor.

```
@Override
public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
    ClientHttpResponse response = execution.execute(request, body);

    String requestString = new String(body);

    // Calling this method because when we make a POST or PUT request and get an error
    // response.getBody() throws IOException. But if we call response.getStatusCode() it works fine.
    // I don't know the reason.
    // I asked a question on stackoverflow
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47429978/resttemplate-response-getbody-throws-exception-on-4-and-5-errors-for-put-and
    response.getStatusCode();
    String responseString = new String(ByteStreams.toByteArray(response.getBody()), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
...
}
```

This is the custom error handler

public class RequestErrorHandler implements ResponseErrorHandler {

```
@Override
public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        if (!response.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
    JAXBElement<ErrorType> root = null;

    try {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ErrorType.class);
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

        root = jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(
                response.getBody()), ErrorType.class);
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        throw new IOException("XML converting error. Cannot convert response to ErrorType");
    }

    ErrorType error = root.getValue();
    throw new VcloudException(error);
}
}
```

Comment: What response body are you expecting for a `401`?

Comment: Actually it doesn't matter if the server sent a response body or not. ,if it didn't send any response body, i want to set responseString as null. But it throws exception.

Comment: Did you see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47467572/4545442 ? May be It will be helpful..

Comment: In your error message `Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://example.com.11/api/sessions`. Is this URL just a typo or it's actually changing the URL to request?

Comment: Also, @SalihErikci are you sure that exception is being thrown by `response.getBody()` and not `ByteStreams.toByteArray(..)`? Because if an I/O exception is thrown, rest template tends to wrap it with `ResourceAccessException`

Answer (score 4):

Use **HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory** instead of SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory.

Also add dependency to 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient.

HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory  ccan read body when status is 401.

Comment: I tried your solution but it gives me the following exception:
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: Now you have another problem, not strictly related to your first. Now you must import certificate. Maybe helpful will be this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33497874/resttemplate-with-pem-certificate

Answer (score 0):

I do not think, `ResourceAccessException` is being thrown by `response.getBody()`, instead seems to be that `ByteStreams.toByteArray(...)` is sending probably a `null` stream in response.

Can you please try debugging if `response.getBody()` is `null` or it's `ByteStreams.toByteArray()`. Because [RescourceAccessException](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/ResourceAccessException.html) is thrown when an I/O error occurs.

Answer (score -1):

Spring RestTemplate as default generates an error when httpstatus is not 200.

In my past project what I did is to add a custom `org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler` to the rest template.
You may wrote a class like this:

```
public class SimpleRestErrorHandler implements ResponseErrorHandler
{
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SimpleRestErrorHandler.class.getName());
    @Override
    public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException
    {
        int statusCode = response.getStatusCode().value();
        if( logger.isDebugEnabled() )
        {

            logger.debug("STATUS CODE ["+statusCode+"] ");
        }
        //Generate Error only when HTTP Status code is 500
        if( statusCode == 500 )
        {

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException
    {
      //Here you can manage the error (in this sample only the http status code = 500
    }

}
```

Then I added this to my rest template:

**XML configuration sample**

```
<bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">        <constructor-arg ref="bufferingClientHttpRequestFactory" />         <property name="errorHandler" ref="simpleRestErrorHandler" />       <property name="messageConverters">             <list>
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
                    <constructor-arg value="#{T(java.nio.charset.Charset).forName('UTF-8')}" />
                </bean>
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter" />
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter" />
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SourceHttpMessageConverter" />
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter" />
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter" />
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter" />
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter" />          </list>         </property>         <property name="interceptors">          <!-- Custom interceptors -->        </property>     </bean> <bean id="bufferingClientHttpRequestFactory" name="bufferingClientHttpRequestFactory"       class="org.springframework.http.client.BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory">      <constructor-arg ref="simpleReqFact" />     </bean> <bean id="simpleRestErrorHandler" class="handlers.SimpleRestErrorHandler" />
```

**Java config**

```
@Config
public class restTemplConfig {
 @Bean
 public RestTemplate restTempl() {
  RestTemplate result = new RestTemplate();
  //Add converters
  //Add custom error handler
  result.setErrorHandler(new SimpleRestErrorHandler());
 }
}
```

I hope it's useful

Comment: I already have a custom handler and maps the error status codes. But i get the exception in the interceptor, before hitting to custom error handler.

Comment: May you post the resttemplate configuration?

Comment: Added the resttemplate config.

Comment: I don't see where you add the ErrorHanlder to your RestTemplate

Comment: Forgot to add that line. Added

Comment: This is strange.. may you add your RequestErrorHandler too?

Comment: What I see is that you always generate error when httpstatus code is not  2xx. This means that in your scenario when service gives out 401 as status code you'll receive error. I guess you should adapte the hasError method

Comment: But the code doesn't even go to that part of the code.